# If I stock a floor and then remove the worker from that floor, does the item continue to sell?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I recently stocked a floor and then moved that worker to a different floor (as I completed building a different [dream job][ floor shortly after he finished stocking).   I noticed that the lights stayed on, but the green check mark went away...  Does this item continue to sell with the worker gone?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it does continue to sell. Just keep an eye on the shop and you'll notice customers still streaming in to buy stuff.

Comment: This works whether the floor is staffed partially or even not at all.  If you build it, they will come.